# CloudResourceManager api for project - 'setLabels'

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Will the setLabels api method be added for google manage resource project? If not, how can I add labels without using the update method for the project?

Answer (score 1):

During project creation time you can [add a label](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#using_api) using Resource Manager API and also able to [update](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/update) the label of a project.